# How do I know when a service was added to boto3?

Tags: python-2.7, boto3

I have a tool which requires boto3's direct connect functionality. However I cannot tell from which version onwards boto3 includes this functionality.

Is there any way to obtain the older version of the docs to see at which point direct connects were added?

At this point in time the latest is 1.4.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boto3 development is an open source initiative. So you can always checkout [botocre](https://github.com/boto/botocore.git) development repository for the release notes, or ask question there.

[changelog.rst](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst) will show a brief list of changes.
Then use following command to switch to specify tag version and look for the date of commit.

```
git checkout tags/<version_name>
```